# Replace an iframe for href in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to automatically replace when some iframe is in the HTML code and be replaced with an href for example because the iframe is not properly shown when it is received by email. So as an example if I have:

```
<iframe class=\"ql-video\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/Lorem\"></iframe><p><br></p>
```

It should be replaced with:

```
<p><a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?Lorem\" target=\"_blank\">https://www.youtube.com/watch?Lorem</a></p>
```

Comment: Do you replace the iframe on the server side? With Node?

Comment: No. In the frontend. I was thinking about a .replace() but I am just a noob and not sure how to do it.

Comment: I don't think, that this is a good idea, because most Email apps also block JavaScript execution, so nothing would happen in the most cases. I can give you an answer how to replace the iframe, but I don't think, that that would be helpful.

Comment: You can simply add the A tag before or after the IFRAME - in emails only the A tag will be rendered.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have tried to send the email through sendgrid and nothing is rendered with the iframe but the text appears with the hyperlink with the a tag. That is the reason I was looking for the replace option. But I don't know how to actually do it because the iframe tag is inside the long string so it would have to locate the iiframe beginning and the ending of the substring.